# Accessing on premises Sybase database server from Linux VM in Azure cloud

Tags: azure, sap-ase

I am working on Azure Poc . Is it possible to connect to on premise Sybase database from Azure cloud ?

Can I read and write data into Sybase from Azure cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Look at [Azure Relay Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-protocol) for a code-first approach or [Site-to-Site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal) for an infrastructure one. Also since you're on a Linux VM, why not just SSH tunnel your traffic over? - probably the simplest solution to your conundrum.

There's also [ExpressRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-introduction) which you may want to take a look at if we're talking serious business that needs connectivity, bandwidth and latency guarantees.